# IIS6 can read but not write to .txt/.mdb files?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-6

Recently deploying an mvc4 project to a virtual directory on a shared iis6 server, I was able to get the server to allow reading files (a problem stemming partially from extensionless URLs).

I have not however, been able write anything to the database or to txt file logs, since deployment. Speaking to the hosting service I've been able to determine that the user is Network User, that all users (including asp net) have read/write privileges. I've tried moving the log files into a separate Log folder, also to no avail.

the error I'm getting is:

> "[UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>   'D:\wwwroot\wwwroot1\isphost\psychtech\psychtech.co.il\Testing\Log\LogHttpRequ
>   ests.txt' is denied.]

Any and all ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you hosting with a commercial hosting site? If so they might have made your site _read-only_?

Comment: The IIS works with an user account wich it has more privelegs than an user have.

Comment: thanks Micky for your time. The hosting is indeed commercial. the site however has read/write/modify privileges.

Comment: reporter- thanks for your time as well. I'm not sure I follow your thinking

Answer (score 0):

The message is pretty clear, the user of the app pool under which run the IIS worker of your site can't access this path to write to the file. The problem might be the same to save to your .mdb.

I suggest you to contact your hoster and ask him about this, it will probably be able to help.

On a side note, you may whant to use a proper database as the file/mdb ones aren't meant for load and concurent acces as it can occur in a web environement. It will also be more scalable, more reliable, more secure and more resilient to failure.

Comment: Remy, thanks for your response. Indeed the answer seems self evident. however, granting privileges to all users has not solved the problem. as for the database - you're correct, of course. however, I have no say in the matter.

Comment: Have you try giving the "full control" on this file/folder ? If a user only have the "modify" right, he can't by default modify the file if the owner is not the user itself.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours, the hosting company IT specialist demystified the problem: as I'm deploying an .net 4 application on an iis6 server, the server utilizes a different user, namely: NETWORK SERVICE. Once this service was granted write privileges, the problem was solved. 
I believe this is what reporter was hinting at.
A note of caution: this configuration is highly susceptible to SQL Injection, requiring additional safety measures in the code